# How to dismiss pop ups stacked on top of each other?

Tags: swift, uikit

I have a pop up and once the user is done with the pop up he selects save & next which segues to a new pop up. When the user is done with that one they press the save & finish button and it dismisses the pop up. But the first pop up never gets dismissed so it brings the user back to the first one once they dismissed the second one. How can I dismiss the first one once it segues to the second pop up?

First Vc

```
class NewRecipeViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate{ 
    @IBAction func saveBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if let error = error {
            howAlert(message: "Error updating in Firestore: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        } else {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "SegueIdentifier", sender: self)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Second Vc

```
class AddIngredient: HomeViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

I tried just placing `self?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)` everywhere and I can't seem to get it to work. Most times it either dismisses the first vc and then never segues to the second vc, or it segues to the second vc and then dismisses the second vc instead of the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using delagtes!

```
protocol FileImporterDelegate: AnyObject {
func fileImporter(_ importer: FileImporter,
                  shouldImportFile file: File) -> Bool

func fileImporter(_ importer: FileImporter,
                  didAbortWithError error: Error)

func fileImporterDidFinish(_ importer: FileImporter)
}

class FileImporter {
weak var delegate: FileImporterDelegate?
}
```